# three.js / anime.js / gltfloader - i can't target imported objects - fiddle

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf, anime.js

UPDATE: In the interest of clarity I have made a **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/heiacc/tsf9junL/3/)**, using two pre-exsisting fiddles that produces the same problem.

Desired result: I would like the imported object to be targetable in the same way that 'cube' is.

Here is the [scroll animation fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/onirenaud/p86wzh9v/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=p86wzh9v)

Notice how it adresses 'cube' in cube.position in the timeline:

```
timeline.add({
    targets: cube.position,
    x: 100,
    y: 25,
    z: -50,
    duration: 2250,
    update: camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  })
```

Here is the [object fiddle.](https://codepen.io/siouxcitizen/pen/QroPwJ) - this works as expected.

Here is my [mixed fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/heiacc/tsf9junL/3/)

In my mixed fiddle - If i try to swap out cube.position for mesh.position in the timeline - it throws an undefined error.

[Same?/Similar question on three.js discourse](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/begginer-struggling-to-understand-a-concept-gltfloader/13194/4)

Comment: `load` is an async function, is it possible that you referenced `logo` before loading completed?

Comment: Sorry I have re-read your question.. logo is referenced for the first time after the '//called when the resource is loaded' - is this what you mean? Would I have to add my own argument in the middle of that to wait for it to load before creating logo and scaling?

Answer (score 0):

I got what i wanted by:

1) Creating an addMesh function and calling it in initThree()

2) Creating a mesh = gltf.scene.children

3) Creating a meshGroup from mesh

4) Targeting meshGroup inside of anime.js timeline

```
     timeline.add({
    targets: meshGroup.position,
    x: 100,
    y: 25,
    z: -50,
    duration: 2250,
    update: camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
  })
```

It works [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/heiacc/tL4rw27m/10/)